# setting A name records for Github pages

Tags: github, domain, dns

I'm trying to set up a custom domain on Github Pages, but I don't think I'm doing something correctly.

As indicated in these instructions https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages, I created a CNAME file in the root of my directory with the domain I want to use for my project

```
CNAME

example.com
```

Once that's done, the instructions (same page as linked to above) say that I have to set my DNS

> Top-level domain (TLD)
>
> For a TLD like example.com, you should use an A record pointing to
>   204.232.175.78:
>
> dig example.com +nostats +nocomments +nocmd
>
> ## Look up DNS record for example.com
>
> ## ;example.com.                    IN      A
>
> ## example.com.             3259    IN      A       204.232.175.78

I bought my domain name at Godaddy, but had set the nameservers for zerigo.net (several months ago). If I do 'dig mydomainname.com' from the command line to get information from my domain name, it says that it's hosted by Zerigo

```
9   IN  SOA a.ns.zerigo.net. hostmaster.zerigo.com. 1364449818 10800 3600 604800 900
```

I therefore went to Zerigo.net and (I think) added an A record pointing to 204.232.175.78 by doing this

[image]

The result of doing that created this for my domain name. I'm assuming the A in this image refers to an A name record. It says that it refreshes every fifteen minutes, bu t it's been much much longer than fifteen minutes since I set the A name record...

[image]

So now I have the CNAME file in the Github Pages directory (and I can view the github pages app at the username.github.com/repo, so I know that's working), and I have set the A name (I think) as per the instructions on github pages, but if I visit that domain name nothing happens

Based on what i've told you, have I followed the instructions correctly for setting up a custom domain on github pages?

Update

Zerigo.net has snippets for DNS of frequently used services like Github pages and Google. It's snippet for Github pages provides different information than what Github provides. First of all, the A name it says to set is different than the one on Github's instruction page. Zerigo's starts with 207... while Github provides a number that starts with 204.... Also, Zerigo says that C Name must be set to the Github user name, however, i'm wondering if that's also true if you're not hosting the site from your Github user name but rather from a project. Username and Project Pages are quite different https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages. My page is a project page...

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question for end-users of web applications.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is to add an A record pointing to 204.232.175.78 and to also add a C name record pointing to the Github user account 'username.github.com'

The Github pages snippet (see image posted in OP) created by Zerigo is out of date.

Comment: The IP addresses are different yet again. See https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages.